# How do I include jQuery scripts at the bottom of the <body> tag?

Tags: theming, javascript

I want to include a JavaScript file at the bottom of the `<body>` tag, and I only want to  include it for a specific node type, but my node.tpl.php file's content is only wrapped by `<article>` tag; there is no ` tag in this file. If I do this in the root template.tpl.php file, it will effect all pages, which is not what I want.

Can I do this via theme preprocess functions?

Comment: You may want to glance at these article http://knackforge.com/blog/ganesan/creating-separate-pagetplphp-content-type and http://snipplr.com/view/9219/pagetplphp-theme-by-node-type/  They talk about how to make Content-Type specific templates. This may help get you closer.

Answer (score 1):

The example on the documentation for [`drupal_add_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) can explain this.

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });',
  array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5)
);
```

If you want to add jQuery files, just change `'type'` to `'file'`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: yep, the answer has been updated, plz correct me about any unapproporiate.

Answer (score -1):

Drupal 7 has introduced several new techniques that allow you far greater flexibility and control in the scripts you can have on your Drupal site's pages.

[jQuery is now namespaced](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#javascript_compatibility) to avoid conflicts with other Javascript libraries such as Prototype. All your code that expects to use jQuery as $ should be wrapped in an outer context like so.

```
(function ($) {
  // All your code here
})(jQuery);
```

If you don't, you may see the error `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function` or similar.

Basic module code should go from something like this in Drupal 7:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.example', context).click(function () {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle('show');
      });
    }
  };


})(jQuery);
```

These behaviors are instigated as you declare them in JavaScript so to clarify, there is no need for defining behaviors within a theme's or module's PHP file.

When applying certain behaviors to elements through JavaScript, we apply a class to the element to depict whether or not the effect has been applied.

[Using jQuery Once](http://plugins.jquery.com/once/) (integrated into D7 core), the developer experience of applying these effects is improved. Note that there is also the removeOnce method that will only take effect on elements that have already applied the behaviors.

```
Drupal.behaviors.mybehavior = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('input.mybehavior', context).once('mybehavior', function () {
      // Apply the MyBehaviour effect to the elements only once.
    });
  }
};
```

For best-practice examples, it's helpful to look at (comparatively) simple examples such as `misc/collapse.js` to see how it's done.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a great answer! Unfortunately, it doesn’t really answer this particular question.